# Which of the below query will perform well?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I am trying to understand if there will be any performance benefit in one query than the other in below two queries. Appreciate your help to understand this.

1. This query will be called few thousands to few hundred thousands times in a day, and it could be insert operation or update operation.

--There is a CLUSTERED INDEX ON TYPE,ID ON XYZ table

***Query1:***

```
DECLARE @paramDef NVARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(100)

SET @paramDef = '@Type nvarchar(100), @Id INT'
SET @columnValue = 'testField'

SET @strSql = 
    N'IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM XYZ WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Type = @Type AND ID = @Id)
    BEGIN
        .... insert into XYZ code
    END
    ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM XYZ WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Type = @ReferenceType AND Id = @Id  
                AND ' + @columnname + ' IS NULL)
    BEGIN 
        .... update to XYZ code
    END'

sp_executesql @strSql, @paramDef, @Type = 'abc', @Id = '123'
```

***OR Query2***

```
DECLARE @paramDef NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(100)

SET @paramDef = 'DECLARE @rowExists nvarchar(100), @columnValue nvarchar(100), @Type nvarchar(100), @Id INT'
SET @columnValue = 'testField'

SET @strSql = 
    N'SELECT @rowExists = 1, @columnValue=' + @columnname + ' FROM XYZ WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Type = @Type AND ID = @Id
    IF (@rowExists IS NULL) --row does not exists then insert 
    BEGIN
        .... insert into XYZ code
    END
    ELSE IF (@rowExists = 1 and @columnValue IS NULL)
    BEGIN 
        .... update to XYZ code
    END'

sp_executesql @strSql, @paramDef, @Type = 'abc', @Id = '123', @rowExists = NULL, @columnValue = NULL
```

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you benchmark and inspect the execution plans?

Comment: It is impossible to tell from what is shown here.  The relative efficiency largely depends on how often the conditions are met.  If you are inserting a new row 99% of the time, that is very different than if you only insert 1% of the time.

Comment: Mitch: I haven't done much of that and yes, want to do that once get some chance from current tight deadline as will be doing after long time and will take some time to grasp all the info in plan.

Comment: dan1111, you are right. In my case, this types of calls are part of public API calls. considering more inserts, the Query1 seemed better considering it not reading column values which are not needed. But in this scenario, for now we are sure inserts are more. But in future there could be more updates too based on client's need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried testing both the query with below and tried running it many times for inserts and updates both.

SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON

With this analysis its found that only first time both the query took more time (though 5 ms) but then with plan reuse both performed almost same (1ms) . With this we went with Query2 where there is only one select is used in case of both Inserts/Updates where in Query1 there will be two select in case of update. The conditional parameters in both the query are part of clustered index only so did not see much difference in overall performance.

Thanks all for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

About query 2 please use merge to be fast! 
MERGE  table AS TARGET
USING (some values) AS SOURCE 
ON (TARGET.ID = SOURCE.ID and target.type=source.type) 
WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.columnvalue<> SOURCE.columnvalue
THEN 
UPDATE SET TARGET.columnvalue= SOURCE.columnvalue
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
INSERT (ID, type, columnvalue) 
VALUES (SOURCE.ID, SOURCE.type, SOURCE.columnvalue)

Comment: Thanks Laura. We are using SQL Server 2005 so can't use MERGE there. I might have forgot to mention that.